# Can i see the Logs in Play Market Crashes & ANRs panel?

Tags: android, logging, google-play, android-logcat

To be honest I never used Log for debugging, I was perfectly fine with Toasts and Android Studio debugging. But recently I discovered that error, warn, info logs (Log.e, Log.w, Log.i) are kept inside  apk file, and that is a huge helper. So can i see the Logs(error, warning, info) in Play Market Crashes & ANRs panel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is highly recommended that you turn OFF logging for your production apps that you're uploading to the Play Store.  Writing out to LogCat is a significant burden on performance. http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html

Second, to answer your question, no, you cannot see those logs in the Play Store.  You can see those logs with the phone attached to a computer and using adb or with some 3rd party apps that require a rooted device.

If you're interested in pretty decent crash reports along with a myriad of other information give Crashlytics a try.  It is fantastic.

Finally, if you're relying only on the Play Store to tell you how many crashes and/or ANRs you have then Crashlytics is going to be very eye-opening for you ;)